# How to change gerrit project label permissions from the CLI?

Tags: git, gerrit

I want to add a new Label ACL to gerrit `project.config` from the CLI. How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/shanesmith/gerrit-cli might help

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1) Clone the All-Projects project

```
git clone https://USER@GERRIT-SERVER/a/All-Projects
```

2) Fetch and checkout the refs/meta/config branch

```
git fetch refs/meta/config
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

3) Edit the project.config file

```
EDITOR project.config
```

4) Add, commit and push to Gerrit

```
git add project.config
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/meta/config
```

You can also edit the project.config file using the GUI:

```
Projects > List > SELECT-THE-PROJECT > General > Edit Config
```